# So I would really like to know what this quote means by William Howard Taft

Tags: history

"The intoxication of power rapidly sobers off in the knowledge of its restrictions and under the prompt reminder of an ever-present and not always considerate press, as well as the kindly suggestions that not infrequently come from Congress."

Comment: Welcome Halley!  What do you think it means?

Comment: Bear in mind that it's over a hundred years old and is intended to be ironic if not humorous. Humor was a little different back then.

Comment: this looks pretty self explanatory?

Comment: This single statement contains enough content for several doctoral dissertations in the fields of politics, journalism and sociology  :-)

Comment: The honeymoon's over.

Comment: "WTF, I'm not a king!"

Comment: "Hey!  This isn't the job I signed up for!" :-)

Comment: Damn, reckoned I had it all

Comment: "The pleasure that comes with suddenly coming into possession of great power wears off rapidly when you realize that institutional checks and balances sharply restrict your exercise of that power, and you notice that everything you do is discussed, second-guessed, and criticized in the press and in Congress."

Comment: "Don't try to tell me what to do or what not to do!"

Comment: "Someone tapped my phones!!"

Answer (score 3):

The euphoric celebration of the inaugural ball quickly gives way to the hard work of governing a passionately diverse nation.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a paraphrasing of the OP? I think not.

Comment: An interpretation, @Octopus :-)

Answer (score 1):

My try in ELL terms:

"After being elected, a president will feel like he can do anything for a short time. 
But the pressure of being under constant watch from the press and attacks from publicly elected political enemies will take their toll and bring him back to reality: he's got less power than he hoped for."

Answer (score 0):

Journalists and politicians bring powerful men down to earth

Answer (score 0):

Its an odd statement because it implies that journalists (the press) are inconsiderate ["not always considerate"] with their anti-power statements, but that congress are polite ["kindly suggestions"]. It is difficult to decide whether the statement is being facetious or not.

Comment: Oh, he's being facetious, all right. Politics in them days was a whole lot less restrained than now. Consider the verse bandied about by Grover Cleveland's opponents (referring to his illegitimate child): "Ma, ma, where's my pa? Gone to the White House, haw haw haw!"